# ViewDoesNotExist even when it does

Tags: django, django-views

Here is the thing. 
My urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('snippets.views',
                       url(r'^snippets/$', 'snippet_list'),
                       url(r'^snippets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', 'snippet_detail'),
                       )
```

My views.py :

```
class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):

    def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
        content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
        kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)

    @csrf_exempt
    def snippet_list(request):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            snippets = Snippet.objects.all()
            serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippets, many=True)
            return JSONResponse(serializer.data)

        elif request.method == 'POST':
            data = JSONParser().parse(request)
            serializer = SnippetSerializer(data=data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return JSONResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
            else:
                return JSONResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

I'm following [this](http://django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization.html) tutorial.

I have this error when I'm at local/snippets/ :

> ViewDoesNotExist at /snippets/ Could not import
>   snippets.views.snippet_list. View does not exist in module
>   snippets.views.

Update : The ErrorKey I have after resolving this :

```
KeyError at /snippets/
'id'

Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/snippets/

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.4
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'snippets')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/thomas/.virtualenvs/REST/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/thomas/.virtualenvs/REST/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  77.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/thomas/projets/rest/snippets/views.py" in snippet_list
  21.         serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippets, many=True)
File "/home/thomas/.virtualenvs/REST/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in __init__
  159.         self.fields = self.get_fields()
File "/home/thomas/.virtualenvs/REST/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in get_fields
  206.                 new[key] = ret[key]

Exception Type: KeyError at /snippets/
Exception Value: 'id'
```

Updating the SnippetSerializer class :

```
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'code', 'linenos', 'language', 'style')

    def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
        """
        Create or update a new snippet instance, given a dictionnary
        or deserialized field values

        Note that if we don't define this method, then deserializing
        data will simply return a dictionnary of items.
        """

        if instance:
            instance.title = attrs.get('title', instance.title)
            instance.code = attrs.get('code', instance.code)
            instance.linenos = attrs.get('linenos', instance.linenos)
            instance.language = attrs.get('language', instance.language)
            instance.style = attrs.get('style', instance.style)
            return instance

        return Snippet(**attrs)
```

Comment: What's the filesystem structure?

Comment: @PauloBu the indentation was false, christophe31 resolved the problem !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your `views.py` to:

```
class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):

    def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
        content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
        kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)

@csrf_exempt
def snippet_list(request, pk=None):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        snippets = Snippet.objects.all()
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippets, many=True)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JSONResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        else:
            return JSONResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Also, you  need `pk` as a parameter to the view for it to work fine.

You need to change `class SnippetSerializer(serializers.Serializer):` to `class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):`

Comment: I put the pk=None, but I still have a KeyError. It says "id", only that

Comment: which line is the erro? Can you update the question with the stacktrace?

Comment: How is `SnippetSerializer` defined?

Comment: what is the primary key in your `Snippet` model ? Just remove `id` from fields and see if it work.

Comment: I didn't set any primary key for Snippet, so I guess it's the default value, his id.
If I remove 'id' from the fields I got the error... 'title'

Comment: Check the way the fields are declared: http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html

Comment: If you check the tuto I'm following (http://django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization.html), at the Using ModelSerializers part, you can see how he declares the field. Is it wrong ?

Comment: It inherits from `ModelSerializer` you are inheriting from just `Serializer`

Comment: Well... Finally, here is the problem. I keep having errors like that today, I must be tired, end of the week... Anyway, thanks a lot, I was about to give up !

Comment: class SnippetSerializer(serializers.Serializer): to class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

unindent your `def snippet_list(request):` block, it'll works better.

Your request is not in the global scope of the module. So it can't be found.

Comment: Ohhh... Thanks a lot. Now I have a keyerror at /snippets/.

Description of the error is "id".
Any idea where it could come from ?